# Why OpenAPI does not define '$ref' as allowed property?

Tags: openapi, json-schema-validator

In compare to `draft-07` it defines:

```
{
    "type": ["object", "boolean"],
    "properties": {
        ...
        "$ref": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "uri-reference"
        },
    }
    ...
}
```

Currently I am trying to write validator for [`openapi`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md#specificationExtensions). But validation fails because `openapi` [schema](https://github.com/googleapis/gnostic/blob/master/OpenAPIv3/openapi-3.0.json#L724) (yes, it is schema from google apis) does not define `$ref` as allowed property for `schema`.

Is this a typo? What is recommendation about how to check `$ref` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$ref` is a JSON Reference. It's not part of the `schema` definition, instead it's part of the [`reference`](https://github.com/googleapis/gnostic/blob/master/OpenAPIv3/openapi-3.0.json#L702) definition:

```json
"reference": {
  "type": "object",
  "description": "A simple object to allow referencing other components in the specification, internally and externally.  The Reference Object is defined by JSON Reference and follows the same structure, behavior and rules.   For this specification, reference resolution is accomplished as defined by the JSON Reference specification and not by the JSON Schema specification.",
  "required": [
    "$ref"
  ],
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "$ref": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
},
```

And then other definitions where `$ref` is allowed use `oneOf` *something* or `reference` ([example](https://github.com/googleapis/gnostic/blob/master/OpenAPIv3/openapi-3.0.json#L1008)):

```json
"schemaOrReference": {
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/schema"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/reference"
    }
  ]
},
```

By the way, there are currently two different draft OAS3 JSON Schemas in the official OpenAPI Specification repository. Feel free to try them instead, and provide your feedback in the corresponding discussions.

- [[WIP] Alternative OAS3 JSON Schema](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/pull/1270) ([link to schema](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/49e784d7b7800da8732103aa3ac56bc7ccde5cfb/schemas/v3.0/schema.yaml))
- [OpenAPI v3 JSON Schema](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/pull/1236) ([link to schema](https://github.com/timburks/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/5f3a9a7f547785c3f38001fc0ef82ff621d1bb79/schemas/v3.0/schema.json))

Comment: I figures out that I ask different thing: not that I want. Why `$ref` is not part of JSON Schema `draft-04`? What recommendations how to check `$ref` while validating `draft-04` against itself?

Comment: @EugenKonkov I'd suggest asking these questions in [JSON Schema repository](https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec) - you'll likely get the best answers there.